# detect coordinates of some element on image

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa

Please tell me how to solve this problem.
Where to start and which way to go. 
I have an image with some buttons :
[image]

How can i detect coordinates of blue round button for example?

The difficulty lies in the fact that these are not application buttons, but just a picture on the desktop.
I understand that this is a vast and complex question, but tell me at least the right way.
It will be useful to many people.

The first thing I can imagine is to do a desktop screen, and then try to detect pixels with blue color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do manual image detection because Apple's vision framework already does this.  You can use it to detect rectangular regions, detect text, or recognize and image within an image, depending on your needs.

See [Detecting Objects in Still Images](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/vision/detecting_objects_in_still_images)